# "amplify publish" fails to deploy without any detailed error stack trace

Tags: aws-amplify-cli, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-sdk-js

We are using ***AWS amplify*** to develop our *next.js* application for the first time and trying manual deployment process. We are getting following error when we try to run "*amplify publish*".
This error is frustrating because there is no stack trace to figure out what is causing the issue. I can see the artifacts were successfully loaded to S3 bucket. But deployment fails.

Error:

```
Export successful
✔ Zipping artifacts completed.
✖ Deployment failed! Please report an issue on the Amplify Console GitHub issue tracker at https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-console/issues.
An error occurred during the publish operation
```

I tried to manually upload the zipped file using the "drag and drop". It feels like its stuck with the message Your build is being queued.... for hours now.

Any help is highly appreciated. This is a huge blocker for us.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue.

first run this command

```
amplify configure project
```

after set 'out' to Distribution Directory Path like this.

```
Distribution Directory Path: out
```

[configurations.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDK9M.png)

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.amplify.aws/guides/hosting/nextjs/q/platform/js/

### 1) SSG Only:

Inside `package.json`

```js
"scripts": {
  "build": "next build && next export",
  ...
}
```

Run this command.

```sh
amplify configure project
```

Then, keep every thing the way it is, except this:

```sh
Distribution Directory Path: out
```

### 2) SSG & SSR:

Inside `package.json`

```js
"scripts": {
  "build": "next build",
  ...
}
```

Run this command.

```sh
amplify configure project
```

Then, keep every thing the way it is, except this:

```sh
Distribution Directory Path: .next
```

### Note:

Do not forget to change the **`Image`** in index.js, because currently AWS does not support next/image.
https://docs.amplify.aws/guides/hosting/nextjs/q/platform/js/#deploy-and-host-an-ssg-only-app

Answer (score 0):

Try to put static content on S3 manually.
For example, if you have generated static contents in the `dist/` directory using `nuxt generate`, run the following command:

```
aws s3 sync dist/ s3://{YOUR_BUCKET_NAME}
```

If this solves your problem then try to use CodeCommit for your amplify project until this gets fixed.

GitHub issue: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-console/issues/1369

Answer (score 0):

We resolved the above issue. The issue was with the IAM policies. Once we fixed the role policies we were able to publish and see the progress of the deployment.